# Two Multiple Integrals

Tags: calculus

Could anyone solve this two integrals? I would really appreciate. Thank you!

1. $$\iiint\limits_D y^2 dx dy dz$$
   where $D=\{(x,y,z)|y\geq 0 \text{ and } x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1\}$
2. Using variables change theorem, calculate the next integral using polar coordinates:

$$ \iint\limits_D \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy$$ 
where $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y\in [0, 1] \text{ and } 0\leq x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}\}$

$$x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta
$$

Comment: Some of your formatting went astray. Can you please correct? Regards

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd try to edit, but I cannot understand this.

Comment: i tried to edit ... check it out. if anything wen't amiss, notify!!

Comment: In general, it is good practice to state from where these integrals arise and to state your thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

For example (1): cylindrical coordinates

$$x=r\cos\theta\;\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\;\;,\;\;z=z\;\;,\;\;J=r\;\;,\;\;0\leq \theta\leq \pi\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\limits_0^1dr\int\limits_0^{\pi}d\theta\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r^3\sin^2\theta\, dz=2\int\limits_0^1r^3\sqrt{1-r^2}\,dr\int\limits_0^\pi \sin^2\theta\,d\theta=$$

$$=\frac{4}{15}\int\limits_0^\pi \sin^2\theta\,d\theta=\frac{4}{15}\left.\left(\frac{\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta}{2}\right)\right|_0^\pi=\frac{2\pi}{15}$$

**Disclaimer:** Check carefully the above.

**Added:** Thanks to Michael E2 for the comment below. The correction's been done.

Comment: Still checking ...hold on.

Comment: I get $\frac{2\pi}{15}$ on wolfram:
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^1+\int_0^\pi+\int_0^\pi+%28r+\sin+\theta+\sin+m%29^2\%3B+%28+r^2+\sin+m%29+\%3B+dm+d\theta+dr) using @experimentX 's formulation

Comment: I confirmed your computation on MATLAB, (faster)
\begin{verbatim}
>> syms r
>> syms theta
>> syms z
>> f=r^3*sin(theta).^2
>> int(int(int(f,z,0,sqrt(1-r^2)), theta,0,pi),r,0,1)
 
ans =
 
pi/15
\end{verbatim}

Comment: What J is in this case?

Comment: I think $-\sqrt{1-r^2}\le z \le \sqrt{1-r^2}$, which would explain the missing factor of 2.

Comment: J is the Jacobian, @user58516...and I shall check again for that factor $\,2\,$ that Michael mentions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why you've got $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ as opposed to the usual $\theta \in (0,2 \pi) $

Comment: Because it is given that $\,y=r\sin\theta \ge 0\iff \theta\in [0,\pi]\,$ , @shimee

Comment: @DonAntonio Because $y>0$? I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll simplify question $2$ for you: 
 
$$x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta$$
and 
$$
D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y\in [0, 1] \text{ and } 0\leq x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}\}
$$
$\Rightarrow$ 
$$
\iint\limits_D \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy = \int_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r}{1+r^2} drd\theta = ... = \frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)
$$

Comment: this is the first time i ever wrote so much!! +1

Comment: looks like you forgot to edit the final value .. since limit has been changed.

Comment: @experimentX Thanks, (whoops)

Answer (score 1):

For the first integral, we are evaluating $y^2$ along the hemisphere $ y\geq 0 \text{ and } x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$ of radius 1. Without $y^2$, it should give the volume of hemisphere. We can change into [spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates). The only constraint is $y \ge 0$ so the limit would be as usual except for $0\le \theta \le \pi $, we have

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi (r \sin \theta \sin \phi )^2\; ( r^2 \sin \phi) \; d\phi d\theta dr $$

For the second integral, note that $ 0\leq x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2} \implies x^2+y^2 \le 1$ which is a circle of radius $1$ also $x\ge 0$ and $y \in [0, 1] $0 implies we are evaluating it in the first quadrant of circle. Change into polar coordinate system. The only constraint is in $\theta$ which goes from $0$ to $\pi \over 2$. So the integral is
$$ \int_0^1\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \frac{1}{1 + (r \cos \theta)^2 + (r\sin \theta)^2} r d\theta dr $$

Comment: The limits of integration of the outer integral should be from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal thank you for correction!!

Comment: @experimentX whoops I had $\pi/4$ on my limits of integration (accident), +1 for in-depth explanation. **Rustyn Yazdanpour would like to appeal to the OP to accept experimentX's answer in place of his**

Comment: @experimentX: You are welcome.

Comment: @experimentX 
yours and Don Antonio's answers do not concur: 
\begin{verbatim}
>> 
syms phi
>> f1=(r*sin(theta)*sin(phi) )^2*(r^2*sin(theta))
 
f1 =
 
r^4*sin(phi)^2*sin(theta)^3
 
>> int(int(int(f1,phi,0,pi),theta,0,pi),r,0,1)
 
ans =
 
(2*pi)/15
\end{verbatim}
I'm going to eat some lunch.

Comment: he's using cylindrical coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint\limits_D \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}dxdy = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+r^2}rdrd\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to (1): Letting $B$ be the unit ball and $\Sigma$ be the surface of a ball of radius $\rho$, then by symmetry
$$\begin{align}
\iiint\limits_D y^2 \; dx \; dy \; dz
 &= {1 \over 2} \iiint\limits_B y^2 \; dx \; dy \; dz
 = {1 \over 2} \iiint\limits_B x^2 \; dx \; dy \; dz
 = {1 \over 2} \iiint\limits_B z^2 \; dx \; dy \; dz\cr
 &= {1 \over 6} \iiint\limits_B(x^2+y^2+z^2) \; dx \; dy \; dz\cr
 &= {1 \over 6} \int_0^1\iint\limits_\Sigma \rho^2 \; dS \; d\rho
  = {1 \over 6} \int_0^1\iint\limits_\Sigma  \; dS \;\rho^2\; d\rho
  = {1 \over 6} \int_0^1 4\pi\rho^2 \;\rho^2\; d\rho \cr
 &= {1\over6} {4\pi \over 5} = {2 \pi \over 15}\,.
\end{align}
$$